# How to "squeeze" directory levels

Tags: bash

I have data files buried in deep directory structures for a lot of IDs like:

```
ID1/a/b/c/data1
ID1/d/e/data2
ID1/f/g/h/i/data3

ID2/j/data1
ID2/k/l/m/data2

ID3/m/n/data1
ID3/o/data2
ID3/p/q/r/s/t/u/data3
ID3/v/w/data4
ID3/x/y/z/data5
...
```

Is there a convenient way to "squeeze" those directories so that data files are put immediately under each IDs? Like:

```
> ls ID1
data1 data2 data3

> ls ID2
data1 data2

> ls ID3
data1 data2 data3 data4 data5
```

Comment: Are you looking to physically move the files, or are you looking for a shortcut so you don't have to type as much in the shell?

Comment: I want to physically move the files. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a pattern similar to this:

```
find ID1/*/ -type f -exec mv -t ID1 {} +
```

`ID1/*/` — look in all directories of `ID1`

`-type f` — look only for files

`-exec mv -t ID1` — invoke `mv` on found files and move them to the `ID1` directory

`{} +` — `find` will replace these args with the names of the files when it invokes `mv`

---

In a loop to cover all directories:

```sh
for dir in ID*/ ; do
    find $dir/*/ -type f -exec mv -t $dir {} +
done
```

---

Note: whitespace in directory names will require a different solution.

Comment: On Ubuntu: `mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...`

Comment: mv -t is a special linux thing I think.  It is documented here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv  but not here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1p.html or here: https://ss64.com/bash/mv.html

Comment: @Jerry yes, it's a GNU extension. POSIX mv only has -i and -f

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible pattern for systems that do not support the `mv -t` option:

```
find ID1/*/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} ID1
```

`-type f` — look only for files

`-print0` — output list of files to stdout separated with NUL characters

The `xargs` utility will receive the output from `find` on its stdin.  The `xargs` options are:

`-0` — accept NUL-separted input

`-I{}` - use the string `{}` to tell `xargs` where to replace the command line pattern with actual input (one at a time)

`mv {} ID1` — the `mv` command invoked by `xargs` where `{}` will be replaced with the pathname of one file at a time.  `mv` will be invoked as many times as there are files passed from `find`.

---

In a loop to cover all directories:

```
for dir in ID*/ ; do
    find $dir/*/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} $dir
done
```

Comment: @oguz I think most BSD-based systems.  My Mac is in this category.

Answer (score 0):

Second "find" statement to clean up the empty directories

```
for i in `ls`
do
  find $i -type f -exec mv {} $i \;
  find $i/* -d -type d -exec rmdir {} \; 
done
```

Comment: This would (unintentionally) delete any symlink and fifos (and device files).

Comment: @rtx this is true if it was applied without any context to the wrong point in the filesystem but the same argument goes for rm -rf *

Comment: @rtx given the above this would be a safer solution for removing the directory files find $i/* -d -type d -exec rmdir {} \;

Comment: feel free to go ahead and revise (edit) your answer with the improvement